# how to get Client id and client secret at yahoo developer portal

Tags: google-chrome, single-sign-on, yahoo, clientid

I want to create an app in yahoo developer portal to get client id and secret and in Redirect URI http is not accepting only https is accepting so how to resolve that ?
Because my passport js is running on localhost:3000 and i want to do yahoo social login through passport js .

I have tried with http to get client id and secret but it is not accepting only https is accpting. and my cde of nodejs is running on localhost:3000 and the callback uri is http://localhost:3000/auth/yahoo/callback